# export matlab file to txt file with delimiter

Tags: matlab, text, export

I have 2 column vectors named t and f which looks like this:

```
t=
1
2
3
4
5
```

and

```
f=
10
20
30
40
50
```

I would like to make a txt file which looks like this:

```
1,10
2,20
3,30
4,40
5,50
```

I tried the next codes but nothing worked so far:

```
vec_char=char(44*ones(1,length(t)))'; %vector of comma's

filename=fopen('functiondata.txt','w');
formatspec='%d %s %d\n';
data={t,vec_char,f};
[nrows,ncols]=size(data);

for row=1:nrows
    fprintf(filename,formatspec,data{row,:});
end
fclose(filename);
```

if theres something better to do, it would be nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I highly suggest you use [`dlmwrite`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dlmwrite.html).  This takes a matrix as well as the name of the file you want to write and writes it to file.  The default delimiter that separates the numbers are commas, which is what you want.

Try this:

```
t = (1:5).'; f = (10:10:50).'; %// Your data
dlmwrite('functiondata.txt', [t f]);
```

Opening up `functiondata.txt`, we get this:

```
1,10
2,20
3,30
4,40
5,50
```

## Note

If you are using Windows, the new line character will not be put in properly when `dlmwrite` is called.  You need to specifically state this when calling `dlmwrite`:

```
dlmwrite('functiondata.txt', [t f], 'newline', 'pc');
```

Comment: theres no \n in it. the result is like 1 big line:

Comment: @ben - Check my edit.  I suspect you are using Windows.

Comment: @ben - No problem at all.  Good luck!